# find id of element

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any way of determining the id attribute of any html element.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice - Be specific! If you ask a vague question, you'll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

Comment: now when I gave specific one, can u giv me ans.

Comment: it works best if you put in the clarification as an Edit to your question itself!! Also shouting will usually get you nowhere - fast!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you edit your question to represent accurately what you are looking for.

Based on your comments, if you are looking for the FIRST DIV, use something like this:-

```
x=document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
if (x!= 'undefined' && x.length > 0 ) 
   document.write(x[0].id);
```

Comment: ya I tried this code but this too not giving me the id, '_firebugConsole' is the msg I get. FYI I have firebug installed in ff.

Comment: @Rahul Utb - can you view your HTML Source and search for  _firebugConsole and see if there is actually a div of that name? I am not sure how firebug works internally...

Answer (score 5):

It's simple as pie:

```
var id = anyElement.id
```

The reverse function (determine element by id):

```
var anyElement = document.getElementById(id);
```

Comment: sorry its not at all solving my problem. Actually I want to determing the id of FIRST DIV element in my page. This div is just after body.

Comment: neither it gave me id of body element.

Comment: why then var id = anyElement.id, not giving id of my page's BODY attribute

Comment: ? You never said anything about getting the body (`document.body.id`) or the first div in the page (`document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id`).

Comment: ya I tried this code but this too not giving me the id, '_firebugConsole' is the msg I get. FYI I have firebug installed in ff.